# Parallel reads from S3

Tags: multithreading, amazon-s3, parallel-processing

Is there an issue while doing massive parallel reads of a file from S3  (or a set of files in the same bucket)?

I see some inconsistencies in my downloaded data and I wonder if this could be the issue.

Any suggestions for a fix?

Comment: You can download S3 file parallel. There should not be any issue while downloading

Answer (score 0):

S3 is not a strong consist system. It is either eventually consist or read-after-write consist depends on the region you selected. See "Q: What data consistency model does Amazon S3 employ?" http://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/ for more detail.